# How do I make a stream reader not block in python? Asyncio or concurrent futures?

Tags: python, streaming, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I have a single threaded stream reading loop that needs some concurrency adding to it to improve performance, but I don't understand which is the correct solution to use, in particular because I need to have a "clock" that ticks even if the stream has no data.

In pseudo code:

```
while True:
   wait until either (streamHasData) or (timeNow > lastLoopTime + minStep)

   if streamHasData:
       processData()

   houseKeepingTasks()
       
   lastLoopTime = timeNow()
```

Currently I have a `readStream()` function that blocks until data appears.  I could make that async, but then I'd still have to await it somewhere which would make it block again?  So I don't see how asyncio helps?  With concurrent futures I could run `readStream` on a thread, then loop with `time.sleep(0.01)` and keep checking if the readStreamFuture has finished, or if it is time to do `houseKeepingTasks`.  And for extra efficiency I can run houseKeepingTasks as another future.

I feel like asyncio should be able to help here, but I can't see how, since wherever I put the await, it will just block to that point, and I'm back where I started.  I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about asyncio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand how Asyncio works. In particular this is incorrect:

> I could make that [function] async, but then I'd still have to await it somewhere which would make it block again

The `await` does *not* mean that the following expression "blocks". All it does is allow for a context switch by the event loop at that point. The surrounding coroutine basically tells the event loop:

*"This could take a while. If you have something else to take care of, go do that. But please check back with me some time later."*

This means the `await` only blocks *that coroutine*, not the entire thread.

Here is a small demo for you:

```py
from asyncio import (
    Event,
    TimeoutError,
    create_task,
    gather,
    run,
    sleep,
    wait_for,
)


async def loop(flag: Event):
    while True:
        try:
            await wait_for(flag.wait(), timeout=3)
        except TimeoutError:
            print("Took too long...")
        else:
            print("Something happened!")
            flag.clear()


async def flag_setter(flag: Event):
    i = 0
    while True:
        print("Iteration", i)
        if i % 5 == 0:
            flag.set()
        await sleep(1)
        i += 1                                          

async def main():
    flag = Event()
    loop_task = create_task(loop(flag))
    setter_task = create_task(flag_setter(flag))
    await gather(loop_task, setter_task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\rStopped")
```

Output:

```
Iteration 0
Something happened!
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Took too long...
Iteration 3
Iteration 4
Iteration 5
Something happened!
Iteration 6
Iteration 7
Took too long...
Iteration 8
Iteration 9
Iteration 10
Something happened!
Iteration 11
...
Stopped
```

Hope this helps and puts you on the right track.

### PS

If you want to add a timeout to awaiting "something to happen", you can do that with [`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for). I expanded the example to show how you can use it.

Comment: Oh, wow, that makes so much more sense than the docs and things.  The outer loop itself has to be async. This Event object also seems to be a critical piece of magic.   So rather than await for EITHER of two events, I can just have a single event set from two different async functions?  Or is that asking for deadlock type troubles...

Comment: @Corvus Sure you can do that. But I just used `Event` for demonstration purposes. It's just a [synchronisation primitive] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html). What tools will make sense for you, depends on your specific use case. Maybe a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) will be useful. Play around with it a bit and try to simulate your actual use case to get a feel for what works. Just be aware that the actual stream reader needs to be a coroutine. Otherwise it will block the thread.

Comment: @Corvus I expanded the example code to show how you can use `wait_for` since it seemed like you wanted such a mechanism in your pseudo code. That way you don't necessarily need to keep track of the last time "something happened", just define a timeout once.